# PHP If statement, suitable?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, html-table

I'm working on a small university assignment to build a simple e-commerce engine using PHP for a website.

I currently have the following script setup to display products within a category, all of which are retrieved from a MySQL database.

```
http://example.com/category.php?id=2
```

The problem I am currently having is that for each product displayed the script is simply echoing each one side by side into a new table entry. This is causing them to go across the page rather than vertically.

What would be the best way to alter this code to have for example a maximum of three products per row? An If loop or something along those lines? Would appreciate the support!

```
<?php

//Create Session
   session_start();

//Connect to database
   include "conn.php";

//Retrieve Header
   include "header.php";

//Get Category ID 
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $CategoryID = $_GET['id'];

//QUERY collects product name, and product ID.
    $q="SELECT ProductID, ProductName, Price,img FROM Products WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";

//QUERY collects Product Category descriptions
    $d="SELECT `Desc` FROM ProductCategories WHERE CategoryID=$CategoryID";

//retrive and execute SQL query results and save into a variable
    $result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$d) or die(mysql_error());

//Retrieve Product Category Description
    echo "<div>";
    while ($myResult = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)){ //Create an array
        echo "<p>".$myResult[0]."</p>";
    }
    echo "</div>";

//Retrieve Products in category
    echo "<div align='center'><table border='1px' bordercolor='#000000' width='200px'><tr>"; //Define table, row and div containing each product

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ //Create an array

        echo "<td>"; //Create table cell
        echo "<p><img src=".$row[3]."></p>"; //product image small (250x250 Pixels)
        echo "<p  align='center'><a href='product.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]." </a></p>"; //Product ID Link and Name
        echo "<p align='center'>&#163; ".$row[2]."</p>";
        echo "</td>"; //Close table cell
    }
    echo "</tr></table></div>";//Close table, div and row
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

// Retireve Footer
include "footer.php";
?>
```

I am new when it comes to programming of any kind, so would appreciate patience/any support you could give me. Also I am aware of the SQL injection problem and will fix this at a later date.

Comment: I removed the link to your page since your code has some SQL Injection flaws. never show your code and the site it runs on. Even if you want to change it later.

Comment: just a tip. Don't build the mindset of I'll do it later with security. That can end up being costly.

Comment: You can easily get a workaround with `mysql_real_escape_string`, although it is depracated, you can quickly solve your injection flaw.

Comment: That's great advice there much appreciated! :)

Comment: That is some very bad advise Lisa, since that doesnt solve anything in his case. Unless he also puts the qoutes in `CategoryID='$CategoryID'`. mysql_real_escape_string on numbers is the best way to get security flaws and a false sence of security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you would keep track of your while iterations with a counter then everytime you hit `$counter%3 === 0` (replace 3 with whatever you want per row) you would close the `tr` and start a new one:

```
$counter = 0;
$perRow = 3;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ //Create an array
    if($counter === 0) {
        echo '<tr>';
    } else if ($counter%$perRow === 0 ) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    echo "<td>"; //Create table cell
    echo "<p><img src=".$row[3]."></p>"; //product image small (250x250 Pixels)
    echo "<p  align='center'><a href='product.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]." </a></p>"; //Product ID Link and Name
    echo "<p align='center'>&#163; ".$row[2]."</p>";
    echo "</td>";
    $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ //Create an array

    echo "<tr><td>"; //Create table cell
    echo "<p><img src=".$row[3]."></p>"; //product image small (250x250 Pixels)
    echo "<p  align='center'><a href='product.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]." </a></p>"; //Product ID Link and Name
    echo "<p align='center'>&#163; ".$row[2]."</p>";
    echo "</td></tr>"; //Close table cell
}
echo "</table></div>";//Close table, div and row
```

The TR needs to be inside the while since tr is a row

Comment: Doh, oh dear... how did I miss this, thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: if you need 4 on a same line you need to have a counter that closes and opens the tr each 4 iterations like prodigistation said let me know if you need help with it

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the old fashion way with tables and iteration counters. You could also use a more CSS based approach.

Loop your result set, and build the inner HTML part (rows, columns)

```
$rows = '';
while ($myResult = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)){ //Create an array
    $rows .= '<div class="inner">'.$myResult[0].'</div>';
}
```

Decide on the width of the inner columns x and make them float left or right, And make the outer div width * x

```
<style type="text/css">
div.box {
  width:900px;
}

div.inner {
  float:left;
  width:300px;
}
</style>
```

And finally echo your HTML

```
<div class="box"><?php echo $rows; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to keep track of the position you're at. If you want 3 cols per row it would be something like:

```
$count = 1;

echo '<table>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  $tmp = $count % 3; //get the remainder

  if ($tmp==1) {
    if ($count!=1) {
      //not the first row so close the last one
      echo "</tr>";
    }

    //start row
    echo "<tr>";
  }

  //show your <td> info

  $count++;
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```